# onTabSelected Selected Not Called

Tags: android, tabs

I have just migrated my old `ActionBar` to new `TabLayout` ( Support Material Design ).

Everything is great but I can't intercept tab selection
The method `onTabSelected` is only called the first time `TabLayout` is displayed, but when clicking tabs, nothing happens!
Any idea what's wrong with this code?

```
 tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if (mViewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager();
    }
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            numTab = tab.getPosition();
            prefs.edit().putInt("numTab", numTab).apply();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

When you call `setupWithViewPager`, this will internally call `setOnTabSelectedListener(new ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));`, overriding your `OnTabSelectedListener`.

Instead, your listener should extend [TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.html), then override `onTabSelected()` and call `setOnTabSelectedListener()` after `setupWithViewPager()`:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
  new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        super.onTabSelected(tab);
        numTab = tab.getPosition();
        prefs.edit().putInt("numTab", numTab).apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are spot on, this solved a similar bug for me. However, there is no mention of this fact in the documentation for TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener. Your answer should be placed in the official android documentation. My primary reference should be the documenation, not stack overflow. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: The above answer is correct! But there is no need to extend the listener. Just calling the tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager) before the tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener resolves this.

Comment: @FaizanAbidNaqvi - you still need to extend `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` if you want custom behavior in `onTabSelected()` yet still want tab selection events to change the selected page.

Comment: I'm was using this `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` before and was doing `viewpager.setCurrentItem` inside `onTabSelected()` , and even didn't knew that this `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` existed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a somewhat fuller example with three tabs. It uses the newer `addOnTabSelectedListener` rather than `setOnTabSelectedListener`.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
        (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.i("TAG", "onTabSelected: " + tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onTabUnselected: " + tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onTabReselected: " + tab.getPosition());
    }
});
```

Notes:

- `onTabSelected` and `onTabUnselected` are called every time there is a change in tabs.
- `onTabReselected` is called whenever a tab is clicked again while it is already showing.