# Navigation in TabLayout in android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am clicking a button in one of fragments of tab and using viewPager.setCurrentItem(index) to change the view but the problem is that I want to invoke onTabSelected function whenever I click the button.
This will help me in using tabLayout.setTextColors(..) function .
Please help.

Comment: possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904265/ontabselected-selected-not-called

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the `TabLayout` object first with your `ViewPager` using the following method:

```
 mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
 mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
```

And only after you can set the `setOnTabSelectedListener` object to your `TabLayout`.

Comment: My method is working perfectly normally but not in case of button click only