# Tab Layout Select method does not call onTabSelected in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

My application is using Tab Layout . I am creating four tabs in MainActivity(This is the activity which gets launched when i open the Application).
Each tab is associated with a fragment using viewpager . Please refer the below code:

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pagerAdapter = new MainFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

// Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        super.onTabSelected(tab);
    }});
```

This is what i am doing in the onCreate method of the MainActivity.
By default the application shows the first tab as the selected tab . But i want to show the 2ndTab as the selected tab every time application is launched fresh.

So for this i am using following code in the onResume method of MainActivity:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select(); //position 1 - means second tab , 0 means tab 1
```

This api selects the 2nd tab properly. 
But Problem 1:-
it does not call the onTabSelected method which i have overridden.

Problem 2: Right After calling tab.select, when i try to get the fragment associated with the 2nd tab, it returns null.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
    Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + 1); // position 1 is for 2nd tab.
    }
```

here page is coming as NULL. But if i try to get the page after 2 seconds (using Android Handler postDelayed ). It gives me the proper page value .This is how i get it using handler:

```
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
          tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
          handler.postDelayed(getFragment, 2000);
        }
       private Runnable getFragment = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment page = null;
 page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + 1); // position 1 is for 2nd tab
        }
    };
```

Now the page value will come proper from the run method.

So how do i resolve problem 1 and is the using handler solution good for second problem.

Comment: Here is the explanation why #1 is not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904265/ontabselected-selected-not-called

Comment: @Alex i am already following the guidelines mentioned in the link provided by you. I get the onTabSelected callback when i swipe or select any tab .
My problem is that  when i select a tab programatically using tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select() . This API does not trigger the onTabSelected callback. But internally when i check the implementation of this API it triggers the onTabSelected callback . But some how i am not able to receive it .

Comment: man simply add a line viewPager.setCurrentPage(1);

Comment: @RushiAyyappa will that call the onTabSelected callback?

Comment: yes. When you are using setUpWithViewPager all the 6 methodds ,3 of viewpager and 3 of tabs will get called.

Comment: did it helped you? @Pardeep Kr

Comment: @RushiAyyappa i am trying ..

Comment: @RushiAyyappa it does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127363/discussion-between-rushi-ayyappa-and-pardeep-kr).

Answer (score 1):

Hey please check the code below:

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pagerAdapter = new MainFragmentPagerAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

// Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
 tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

   viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new  
  TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    super.onTabSelected(tab);
}});
```

Comment: this looks to be working , i tried adding the viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); after adding the viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener ....But i still do not understand the cause of it

Comment: please accept the answer i will explain you on chat

Comment: to get clear idea about how viewpager works put Logs in onPageSelected,onPageScrollled,onPageunselected,onTabSelected,onTabReselected,onTabUnselected and read logs

Comment: you have any idea about problem 2