# In Tablayout tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() method not working

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have three Tab with fragment inside activity but method addOnTabSelectedListener not working and my fragment is working properly and I also have viewPager when I use to debug it is not going inside the method

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    pos = intent.getIntExtra("position",0);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
              tabLayout.getTabAt(pos).select();
                tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                        R.color.white));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                            R.color.white));
                }
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
               /* toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                        android.R.color.white));*/
                tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                        android.R.color.white));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                            android.R.color.white));
                }
            } else {
               /* toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                        R.color.white));*/
                tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                        R.color.white));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Shop.this,
                            R.color.white));
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this way,

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
 new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
      //for selected tab, write your code here...
  }
});
```

for detailed and much clear explanation, visit this link [onTabSelected Selected Not Called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30904479/5353830)

Comment: newTabLayout what is this

Comment: sorry, use your Tablayout reference ' tabLayout ', not 'newTabLayout ', I will change the answer

Comment: tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
                new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        super.onTabSelected(tab);

                    }
                });

Comment: on debug not going inside method

Comment: Sorry, I have changed my answer there was typing error, can you try that, again sorry for error.

Comment: its ok i am trying